# How to get smooth scrolling in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I am just wondering, how do I get smooth scrolling in Nautilus?

Comment: Not answer to your question, but still related: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/4849/

Comment: This is out of date. Nautilus supports smooth scrolling at least in 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in Nautilus, sorry.

Comment: Hello Roland ! It seems like you are right :)

Comment: @Vincenzo: lol. It's needed in GTK+ first, then Nautilus will get it automatically.

Comment: Just an observation, is smooth scroll available in KDE ?

Comment: @Vincenzo: Not that I know of.

Comment: Thank you Roland. I noticed that Dolphin of KDE 4.5-4.6 works smoother. Perhaps, it a matter of programming platform.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recent version of Nautilus that includes smooth scrolling (introduced in GTK 3 or so). Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 have smooth scrolling in Nautilus and other GTK3 apps.

Comment: Does it work for mouse also? or just the trackpads?

Comment: I don't know that I have a mouse that is "smooth", the mouse wheel is usually step by step.

Comment: Could you tell which mouse do you use?

Comment: One that feels like it moves in steps.

Comment: I mean which brand and model. I use logitech gaming mouse, it also moves in steps, but the scrolling is not smooth, except in Firefox, which has implemented the smooth scrolling itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a programer but I'm not sure it's a gtk+ problem, it seems more like a mouse configuration problem. If you scroll down with the mouse wheel it scrolls jumping 3 lines each little movement you do (sorry I can explain it better, my english...) but if you scroll down by clicking the side bar and dragging it down, the scrolling is perfectly smooth.

What I mean is, it CAN be a smooth scroll, the problem is in the way the scrolling is made trough the mouse wheel. Somebody could do a hack so the mouse wheel somehow "emulates" the sidebar click-and-drag.

I whish it helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi! I will be very glad if (may be) later somebody will implement such behaviour for smooth scrolling.